# Docker WSL 2 installation is incomplete

Tags: windows-10, docker, wsl2, docker-for-windows

After substituting [Docker Desktop on Windows 10](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) with a more recent version, clicked to start it and got the following error

[image: WSL 2 installation is incomplete]

> WSL 2 installation is incomplete
>
> The WSL 2 Linux kernel is now installed using a separate MSI update package. Please click the link and follow the instructions to install the kernel update:
>
> https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel
>
> Press restart after installing the Linux kernel

By default, in Settings > General the option "Use the WSL 2 based engine" was already selected. This might be due to me already having Ubuntu 18.04 LTS locally.

If I go to Docker Desktop Settings > Resources > WSL INTEGRATION

[image: Docker WSL Integration]

> You don't have any WSL 2 distro. Please convert a WSL 1 distro to WSL
> 2, or install a new distro and it will appear here.

How can I get Docker running?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's two ways you can get it to work

1. Using WSL 2 based engine.
2. Without using WSL 2 based engine.

---

### 1 - Using WSL 2 based engine

In [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel) under "Download the Linux kernel update package".

[image: Update Linux kernal package]

and then Docker will start just fine

[image: Docker running]

---

### 2 - Without using WSL 2 based engine

If the goal is just to get Docker running, one can simply start by unchecking the box that says "Use the WSL 2 based engine". This can give the following error

[image: Required Windows feature(s) not enabled: Hyper-V.]

> Required Windows feature(s) not enabled: Hyper-V.
>
> Switch to WSL 2 based engine?
>
> To enable Hyper-V:
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

So, in PowerShell 7 run the command

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
> -All

[image: Hyper-V in Windows 10]

which requires to Restart the computer to complete the operation. Then, once starting Docker again, you can get the following error

[image: Docker failed to initialize]

> Docker failed to initialize
>
> One or more errors occurred.

Eventually, just by clicking to start again, Docker will start running

[image: Docker running]

[image: docker version]

Comment: I had already installed WSL on my Windows 10 box. So, the 1st suggestion worked for me, after a restart post installation without any hassles. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent answer to the question but I will say, take a peek at Arun's answer as well, FIRST. This did resolve things for me quickly and easily.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. I just had to update WSL by executing:

```
wsl --update
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1149638)

Comment: This does easily answer the question asked. No explanation ,but it does resolve the outstanding issue. Only point I will add is perform a reboot after performing the wsl update command in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Follow guide at [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package).

You need to enable the windows subsystem for linux with command:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

which enables WSL1.